# Grafana plugin signature always marked as "modified" and never valid. Blocking using plugin

Tags: grafana

I am trying to sign the plugin I am working on, but no matter what I have tried it always says grafana is unable to load it because it is “modified”.

I made a brand new backend datasource plugin, ran the basic yarn install and build commands, then the go and mage commands from the readme, then signed it using the docs procedure for the private key, and nothing else. Still says its modified.

Even checked that the hashes of the files in the manifest were the same as what the manifest had, but no matter what it is always marked as modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered and fixed the issue. So the issue was with an img/logo.svg path being "", but I couldn’t modify it in the manifest file by hand after the signature process since that would make it invalid. And resigning would make the \ appear again. So the simple fix is removing the img folder and moving the logo.svg to the /src folder with the other files. Made the change in the logo paths set in the src/plugin.json as well. Then when plugin is signed the manifest file just has logo.svg instead of img\logo.svg and it passes and is viewable from grafana dashboard.

Here is a link to the grafana forum post where we went through this issue in more detail: https://community.grafana.com/t/signed-backend-plugin-keeps-throwing-modified-signature-error/39687